# How to forbid specific methods (from external lib) in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

I could not find much resources on my question so I guess this is not an easy resolution.

We use JodaTime in our codebase and I wish to forbid (or at least warn) using some methods from this library as they are prone to errors (around timezone management).

I tried the reflections library already, without success due to a non released issue.
We used to have a custom sonar rule to handle this but it is not supported by sonarcloud so I looking for another way.

Do you have any lead to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using [ArchUnit](https://www.archunit.org/) for this, which allows you to specify restrictions such as this as unit tests:

```java
public class DisallowedMethodsTest {
    @Test
    public void forbidJodaTimeMethods()
    {
        JavaClasses importedClasses = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages("your.base.package");

        ArchRule rule = noClasses().should()
            .callMethodWhere(target(name("disallowedMethodName"))
                .and(target(owner(assignableTo(DateTime.class)))))
            .because("Your reasons");

        rule.check(importedClasses);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I tried ArchUnit with no success I am very happy to have a (good) excuse to add this in my project !

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something works in unit test environment, [Jeroen Steenbeeke' answer might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67615673/7952738).

If you are looking for something works in production environmen, you'll need `HOOK`.

---

In case you cannot require partners to use `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` to construct related object, I'd recommend you have a look on `AspectJ` if you are working on a regular Java project or `Xposed` if you are working on an Android project.

Both of them could add restrictions without modifing existing codebase nor programming flow.

Answer (score 0):

I solved such kind of problems by writing an interceptor like the following, as explained at https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/interceptors002.htm:

```java
import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;

public class MethodCallTracerInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    Object intercept(InvocationContext context)
        throws Exception
    {
        Method method      = context.getMethod();
        String methodClass = method.getDeclaringClass().getName();
        String methodName  = method.getName();

        if (methodClass.equals("myClass") && methodName.equals("myMethod")) {
            //TODO Raise an exception or log a warning.
        }

        return context.proceed();
    }

}
```